# Криво работает жизненный цикл Activity

Tags: java, android

Я нахожусь в WatchVideoActivity. Вызывается

onstart();

я нажимаю на кнопку и выполняю

```
finish();
        Intent videoActivityIntent = new Intent(this, WatchVideoActivity.class);
        videoActivityIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(videoActivityIntent);
```

После я вижу в логах onstart
onStop.

Почему так происходит, если старый объект Activity должен вызывать onStop. А уже после onStart нового Activity.

Как исправить эту ситуацию?

Comment: Не вижу ничего кривого. Вы вызываете `startActivity()` и запускается новая активити, отрабатывают методы ее жизненного цикла, но старая продолжает выполнятся, так как ничего в ее коде ее не останавливает. `onStop()` первой срабатывает только когда вторая выходит на передний план.

Comment: В смысле. А ка кже finish():

Comment: какова вообще цель ваших манипуляций? вы уничтожаете активити и тут же стартуете ее же из нее же? Вы хотите перезапустить активити? Для этого есть метод `recreate()`

Comment: Ну да хочу уничтожить активити и создать заново. В принципе могу весь код onCreate перенести. Вот только куда. OnResume не смогу краш получится. Надо чтобы код один раз воспроизвелся

Comment: Там проблема еще в том что когда я ломаю активити и создаю новый. То старое активити ломается приложение закрывается и после оно открывается, не красиво это смотрится.

Comment: У активити есть родной метод recreate(), попробуйте его заюзать